# Angular UI Bootstrap tabset with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I'm trying to upgrade my version of bootstrap-ui from 0.14.x to the latest 1.3.2 and I'm encountering some issues regarding the uib-tabset / uib-tab directives.

What I'm trying to do is dynamically create tabs using ng-repeat and have the 'active' tab be handled by expressions or properties of my repeat model.

```
 <uib-tabset type="pills" active="{{activeItem.Id}}"  >
    <uib-tab class="arrow_box"
             ng-repeat="item in myObject.myCollection"
             ng-click="SetActiveItem(item)" id="{{$index}}"
             index="{{item.Id}}">
```

The **index="{{item.Id}}"** binding does not work at all. So I can't seem to set my tab indexes via an expression, which wouldn't be a problem if I could get the uib-tabset to use the active property once the ng-repeat was complete.

activeItem is a property on $scope of the enclosing controller.

Adding this binding results in an error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{item.Id}}] starting at [{item.Id}}].
```

If I omit everything (*the index attribute on uib-tab and active attribute on uib-tabset*) it doesn't throw any errors but it also doesn't select any tabs by default, meaning I need to click one to activate that tab. Even though the documentation states that the defaults are "defaulting to the first tab".

Any reason ng-repeat no longer works properly with this directive set? I'm probably missing something here but I'm stumped.

Thanks

Edit:
Here is a plunkr link showing the issue I'm having.
https://plnkr.co/edit/DWOILq?p=preview

Comment: Try this -  index = "item.Id". Check if it works

Comment: I have tried that too, it doesn't bind the expression so it ends up just being literally index="item.Id" and doesn't interpolate it.

Comment: Shashank is wrong, this should work.  Create a plunk and I'll see if I can offer some guidance.

Comment: Added a plunkr above to original post. Let me know if you figure anything out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out a few more things I realized I made a mistake and did not have to include the brackets for the expression for either binding (active or index).

It just didn't **seem** like they were being evaluated but they actually are.

Here is the code that should work:
**activeItemId** being a property on the parent controller.

```
<uib-tabset type="pills" active="activeItemId">
    <uib-tab class="arrow_box"
             ng-repeat="item in myObject.myCollection"
             ng-click="SetActiveItem(item)"
             index="item.Id">
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Answer (score 1):

First I tried a lot to fix it but then I decided to search in google. I found this [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/5654) .

Your problem is a known problem and will not be fixed. "uib-tab won't toggle active class if uib-tab index is set to dynamic key". You have to take some different approach like use of '$index'.